# Eventbus in vue.js3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I get the following error when using eventbus

```
Uncaught TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default is not a constructor
```

this is main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

this is EventBus.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

I imported it:

```
import {EventBus} from '../assets/js/EventBus.js'
```

and i use it:

```
EventBus.$emit('increase-counter')
```

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/events-api.html#events-api

Comment: There is no `Vue` in Vue 3